# Overlay image inside <div> causing text to move down

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` with a `border:15px`. It has an image on the left-corner as given in the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/user1212/e7Gez/17/

Now, this image is pushing down the text from the top. How can I make the text get `margin-top:0;`

I do not want to use the image as `background-image` since the `15px border` overlaps it.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `float: left;` on your image, see [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7Gez/18/). You can also use a negative `margin-right` on it to prevent it from pushing the text to the left, but then you need to mess with the `z-index` of it and the rest of the content, which means additional HTML markup for styling purposes; see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7Gez/24/).

Comment: The first line has some padding to it. padding-left:0; margin-left:0; do not seem to get the first line at the left margin. The image seems to be pushing the text toward the right. Can you fix that?

Comment: @user544079: Ultimately, I think you're going about this in the wrong way. Using an `<img>` (an inherently space-using tag) to create a background (inherently not space-using) is always going to be awkward. But I think the second Fiddle I posted answers your question-comment here.

Comment: @user544079: Actually, there's a much better way to handle this, using `position: absolute;` -- I suggest you use my newly-added answer instead of this one.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm going to leave my other answer as a more direct "this is how you fix things doing it your way" answer, but I think a better approach here would be to use `position: absolute;` -- this achieves the effect with much less fuss.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7Gez/38/)

I'm styling the image as follows:

```
img#post-backgrnd {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

This forces the image to go to the upper-left corner, which is where we want it (the `top: -1px;` is because the image is slightly misaligned with the border), and `position: absolute;` means it does not take up space, so it doesn't push the text at all. However, done this way, the image covers up the text. The better solution here is to edit the image, fixing the alignment issue (and going to `top: 0;`), and making the white section actually transparent.

If for some reason that cannot be done, you could fix this overlapping issue by using `z-index`, but it means that your parent, your image, and the text need three different `z-index` values, which means that you need a new element for your text. For an example of this, see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7Gez/45/).

Answer (score -1):

Just add `vertical-align:top` to your `<div>` like:

```
.content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 15px solid #E4EAF3;
  /*  background: #ffffff url('http://smitra.net76.net/post-bg.jpg') no-repeat top left;*/
  margin-top:0;
  padding-top:0;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

see it in [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e7Gez/25/)

Comment: Won't that just cause the second line to jump down below the image? Actually, in your fiddle, it doesn't work at all, not even for the first line. Pretty sure you add `vertical-align` to the image, not the parent